# Download automático de dados de um endereço ftp

Tags: ftp

Alguém poderia por favor ajudar-me a baixar dados que se encontram num ftp sempre que eu logar na minha máquina (linux mint) usando um shell script?
Eu já tentei inúmeras vezes, mas sem sucesso. Asseguir vou mostrar as tentativas e os respectivos erros.

```
wget ftp://41.94.65.2:SENHA@ftp.41.94.65.2/CHIBABAVA/data/2017/01/CHIBABAVA_data20170101.csv -P ~/Downloads
```

Erro:

> Resolving ftp.41.94.65.2 (ftp.41.94.65.2)... failed: Name or service not known.
>   wget: unable to resolve host address ‘ftp.41.94.65.2’

Answer (score 3):

Você está pondo o URL no lugar do nome de usuário. Note que o URL está repetido. Se usou substituição de variável, pos a variável errada. Além, disso, a construção do URL de fato está errada.

No lugar disso:

```
ftp://41.94.65.2:SENHA@ftp.41.94.65.2...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^
aqui é o usuário       aqui é o protocolo
```

O correto seria isso para um esquema de URL com usuário e senha:

```
USUARIO:SENHA@ftp://41.94.65.2...
```

Melhor ainda:

```
wget --user=USUARIO --password=SENHA ftp://41.94.65.2...
```